# How can I keep the object to rotate in the range from it's original position/rotation and not to add/remove each time a new rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotateturret : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum RotateOnAxis { rotateOnX, rotateOnY, rotateOnZ };
    public bool randomRotation = false;
    [Range(0, 360)]
    public int rotationRange = 70;

    private void Start()
    {

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (randomRotation == true)
        {
            var rr = Random.Range(-rotationRange, rotationRange);
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rr);
        }
    }
}
```

What it does now it keep adding or removing a random number to the rotation so in some cases the rotation can be 230 or 450 or 21 it's adding/removing in range of -70 to 70 but I want it to add/remove but only 70/-70 from the original start position/rotation.

For example if the game started and the object rotation is at 20 so add/remove 70 the rotation will be randomly between 20+70 and 20-70 maximum it can get to 90 and minimum to -50.

Answer (score 1):

`Rotate` will act relative to the current rotation so you're actually accumulating rotations there. Try this instead;

```
Quaternion initialRotation;

void Start ()
{
    // Save initial rotation
    initialRotation = transform.rotation;
}

void Update ()
{
    // Compute random angle in the range of +- rotationRange
    var delta = (Random.value * 2f - 1f) * rotationRange;

    // Compute rotation from the initial rotation and delta
    transform.rotation = initialRotation * Quaternion.Euler(0f, delta, 0f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe using a "currentRotation" variable and a "startRotation" variable and adding the random value to it will work. I added it to your existing script in the section below.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotateturret : MonoBehaviour
{
public enum RotateOnAxis { rotateOnX, rotateOnY, rotateOnZ };
public bool randomRotation = false;
[Range(0, 360)]
public int rotationRange = 70;
public int startRotation = 20; //create a startRotation value.
public int currentRotation = 20; //create a currentRotation value in case you need to access it later.

private void Update()
{
    if (randomRotation == true)
    {
        var rr = Random.Range(-rotationRange, rotationRange);
        currentRotation = startRotation + rr; //Add the random value to the start value. This also works for negative values.
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, currentRotation); //use the combined value instead of just rr.
    }
}
}
```